# how to assign a variable to another variable without them being related

Tags: swift, reference

I have an AVPlayer that I am assigning to another AVPlayer but I want both of them to be independent from each other. For example: If I create an AVPlayer like this:

```
var player1:AVPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
```

and then I create another AVPlayer with the same video

```
var player2:AVPlayer = player1
```

then say if I called:

```
player2.play()
```

how do I get only player2 to play and not player1? (Note: I do NOT want to create a brand new AVPlayer by initialising it with the same URL for the sake of performance, speed, and other reasons I have as well) Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Classes are copied by reference, struct are copied by value.

As the class you are using is third party, the only choice you have is to create another instance of that class.

So your code should look something like this:

```
var player1 = AVPlayer(URL: url)
var player2 = AVPlayer(URL: url)
```

The both players are independent from each other but have same URL.

**NOTE:** You don't need to specify the data type in this case because it is assumed from the value you are assigning to it. It's redundant to do so and it's better if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a copy of the first `player.currentItem` and initialising a new AVPlayer with the player item:

```
let player1 = AVPlayer(URL: url)
someItem = player1.currentItem.copy()
let player2 = AVPlayer(playerItem: someItem)
```

It works much faster in my case, why retrieve the same video from a url if you already have it!